# Can a console app make use of UWP assemblies?

Tags: .net-core, uwp

Can a .NET Core console app make use of classes in UWP assemblies?

I am only interested in those that do not involve visual elements.

Comment: Yes, UWP APIs could be used in desktop apps. Please take a look at: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a .NET Core app cannot directly reference an assembly that targets the Universal Windows Platform (UWP, `uap10.0`) if that's what you are asking.

So if you for example have a class library that was created using the `Class Library (Universal Windows)` template in Visual Studio, this project is not compatible with any other platform than UWP and cannot be referenced from a .NET Core app/project.

If you need to share code between UWP and other platforms, such as .NET Core, your class library should target .NET Standard instead of UWP.